# How to proceed? CTF challenge (binary file)

Tags: binary, binaryfiles, steganography, ctf, challenge-response

I have a capture the flag situation; I am quite new to this...

The following is given (translated from Brazilian Portuguese): "This challenge requires digging a little deeper than just "strings" to find the correct flag. Parse the attached binary and score the hidden flag."

A file has been provided, I have already discovered it's an ELF file. Also, by using Strings all I can see is gibberish and a message stating that's not the actual thing (MACK{This_is_not_the_flag_youre_looking_for}; if I test this in the password protect uni hotsite it really confirms it's not the flag).

Discovering the type:

file only_a_binary
only_a_binary: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=bf082798faf7253749442fe4166676287754608f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped

Strings results is too long. How to get along? What else should I try? I have searched a lot and nothing helps out...

Comment: The flag has always the following: MACK{flag}

Comment: I am providing the binary from my personal Drive folder: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tcrw1kQ58IQW887ZyWxJJHLOwwha_zFW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, all the help is gonna be awesome! I want to really learn it. But there's few days left for the challenge to be online...

Comment: You will probably need to examine the code in a disassembler. [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com) is quite good. There are others.

Comment: Hi there @r3mainer! All good? Hope you are! So... for now I won't get along on this. But if I decide to learn how to deal with such challenges, I'll come back here and will definetly take a better look at your comment again. Too much to handle rn. Much appreciated ^^